# ¿Porqué no se ejecuta ninguna de las dos sentencias?

Tags: java, condiciones

Alguien me puede decir porque no me imprime  ninguna de las dos opciones VALOR y VALORDOS?

```
package unitat2algoritmes;

public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static final int VALOR = 5;
    public static final int VALORDOS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (VALOR >= VALORDOS) {
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALOR);
        } else if (VALORDOS < VALOR) {
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALORDOS);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Carlos, ninguna de las condiciones se cumple. Por eso no imprime nada. `5 >= 10` es falso y `10 < 5` también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la sintaxis, ponlo así, ya que si no se cumple la primera condición es porque entrará en la segunda siempre. Ya que en éste código ninguna de las dos condiciones se cumplen :)

```
public static final int VALOR = 5;
public static final int VALORDOS = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (VALOR > VALORDOS) {
        System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALOR);
    } else {
        System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALORDOS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias

Comment: Existe un detalle en su código que pasa si tienen valores iguales las dos variables ? hará una validación errónea y una impresión equivocada.

Comment: En realidad no es una solución totalmente válida. Como te dicen, debes tener en cuenta otros escenarios, como que sean iguales. La solución correcta debería ser la de @Dev.Joel.

Comment: Ya esta, editada, ahora sí

Answer (score 1):

No imprime ningún memsaje porque ninguna condición se cumple!

```
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static final int VALOR = 5;
    public static final int VALORDOS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (VALOR >= VALORDOS) {
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALOR);
        } else if (VALORDOS < VALOR) {
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALORDOS);
        }

    }
}
```

Esta es la primera condición:

```
5 >= 10 ? No se cumple, tiene un valor false.
```

Esta es la segunda condición:

```
10 < 5  ? No se cumple, tiene un valor false.
```

Sugiero este cambio para que verifique primeramente si el primer valor es mayor y posteriormente si el segundo valor es mayor:

```
if (VALOR > VALORDOS) {
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALOR);
        } else if (VALOR < VALORDOS){ 
            System.out.println("El màxim és " + VALORDOS);
        }
```

Debes probablemente considerar también el caso cuando sean iguales:

```
if (VALOR == VALORDOS) {
            System.out.println("Los valores son iguales!");
        } else ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría usar la clase [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) para realizar dicha operación (Entre otras : Menor)
que acepta como parámetro los números a comparar

```
System.out.println(Math.max(VALOR, VALORDOS));
```

En su pregunta no especifica pero podría ser que los `números sean iguales` para eso podría añadir una validación opcional, el código quedaría así:

```
if(VALOR==VALORDOS)
    System.out.println("Iguales");
else
    System.out.println(Math.max(VALOR, VALORDOS));
```

o en una sola línea

```
  System.out.println((VALOR==VALORDOS)? "IGUALES" : Math.max(VALOR, VALORDOS));
```

Comment: Una pregunta dev joel de que pais eres? Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No se Ejecuta ninguna sentencia por:

VALOR >= VALORDOS

5 >= 10 => false

VALORDOS < VALOR

10 < 5 => false